# Half-Filling Hubbard Model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, second-quantization

How do I calculate the matrix elements of a 4x4 matrix following the Hubbard model? I am assuming half filling. I have the following states $$\lvert 1 \rangle = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}= \uparrow_1\downarrow_1 \lvert 2 \rangle = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}=\uparrow_1\downarrow_2 \lvert3\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} =\downarrow_1\uparrow_2 \lvert4\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}=\uparrow_2\downarrow_2$$ where state 1 and 4 cannot hop. For context, the Fermi Hubbard model. I know I have to use $$ \langle i \lvert H \lvert j \rangle $$ where $H$ is the Hamiltonian from Hamiltonian Hubbard. I just don't know how to apply it.

Answer (score 2):

Well you literally have to apply the Hamiltonian to those states.
The Hamiltonian reads
$$
H = - t \sum_{\sigma=\uparrow\downarrow}(c^{\dagger}_{1\sigma} c_{2\sigma} + \mathrm{h.c.} ) + U \sum_{i=1,2} (n_{i\uparrow} n_{i\downarrow} )
$$
So for example consider the interaction term on the first site $U n_{1\uparrow} n_{1 \downarrow}$ and apply this operator to the four basis states:
$$
U n_{1\uparrow} n_{1 \downarrow} |1\rangle = 2U |1\rangle ;
\;\;\; 
U n_{1\uparrow} n_{1 \downarrow} |2\rangle = U n_{1\uparrow} n_{1 \downarrow}|3\rangle = U n_{1\uparrow} n_{1 \downarrow}|4\rangle = 0.
$$
The only non-vanishing matrix element of $H$ coming from this term turns out to be $\langle 1|U n_{1\uparrow} n_{1 \downarrow} | 1 \rangle = 2U$.
You can do a similar calculation with $U n_{2\uparrow} n_{2 \downarrow}$ and with the hopping term.
Let me just give an example of application of hopping term, which is the tricky part:
$$
-t c^{\dagger}_{1\uparrow} c_{2\uparrow} |3\rangle =
-t c^{\dagger}_{1\uparrow} c_{2\uparrow} (c^{\dagger}_{1\downarrow} c^{\dagger}_{2\uparrow} )|0\rangle =
+t  c^{\dagger}_{1\uparrow} c^{\dagger}_{1\downarrow} c_{2\uparrow} c^{\dagger}_{2\uparrow} |0\rangle =
+t c^{\dagger}_{1\uparrow} c^{\dagger}_{1\downarrow} (1 - n_{2\uparrow} )|0\rangle =
+t c^{\dagger}_{1\uparrow} c^{\dagger}_{1\downarrow}|0\rangle = +t|1\rangle.
$$
where I have used the anticommutation properties of the fermionic operators and found that the spin up fermion on site 2 jumps on site 1 bringing state $|3\rangle$ into state $|1\rangle$. This term will just give a $+t$ matrix element in the position $(1,3)$ of the matrix $H$.
Notice a subtlety: I have assumed $|1\rangle = c^{\dagger}_{1\uparrow} c^{\dagger}_{1\downarrow}|0\rangle$, but why don't $|1\rangle = c^{\dagger}_{1\downarrow} c^{\dagger}_{1\uparrow}|0\rangle$ ?
This is just a matter of convention, but you need to be consistent with the choice, otherwise the signs will be messed up completely.

Comment: this helps, thank you. Just for clarification, the value that goes in each matrix element is the value after being calculated by both the hopping and interaction terms right?

Comment: Yes! The Hamiltonian is the sum of hopping and interaction, so every entry of the matrix $H_{ij}$ is in principle the sum of the contribution coming from the hopping and from the interaction. However it turns out that interaction contributes to diagonal terms only, while hopping contributes to off-diagonal terms only. This is due to the choice of the basis, which is essentially made by the eigenstates of the interaction term.